# Adding an argument to a mathematical function

Tags: r, gstat

I'm trying to automate a process to produce interpolated geochemical maps.
I've created a loop that essentially starts at column #13 and loops through until #67.

However, part of the IDW code requires the header of the current column for the respective geochemical parameters to be mapped.

For instance; column #13's header is "Ag_ppm", so the original code read:

```
    LogSr.idw = idw(log10("Ag_ppm") ~ 1 , locations=NGSA.SPDF, newdata=NGSA.grid,
                   maxdist=15000, nmin=4)
```

I've been able to obtain the header of the column in interest within each loop using (where i increases by 1 each loop; 13, 14, 15 etc.):

```
    coln <- colnames(NGSA.df[i])
```

However, when I simply substitute the "Ag_ppm" to coln, the line fails with a given error. I've tried various approaches including paste, although everything still results in the same error.

```
    LogSr.idw = idw(log10(coln) ~ 1, locations=NGSA.SPDF, newdata=NGSA.grid,
                    maxdist=15000, nmin=4)
```

> Error in log10(coln) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Is there a reasonably simple approach using the current method?

Comment: One thing: use this `colnames(NGSA.df)[i]` instead. Your version is needlessly copies an entire column of the data, whereas you only want the name of the variable. Please include the name of the package you are using as well as `idw` is not a base R function.

Comment: For that line of code the package is 'gstat'

Comment: I have to admit that I am surprised that `log10("Ag_ppm")` doesn't throw the same error. Try wrapping coln in `get`: `log10(get(coln))`.

Comment: @lmo, that has worked thankyou.

Comment: The working code now is: 
`LogSr.idw= idw(log10(get(coln))~1,locations=NGSA.SPDF,newdata=NGSA.grid, maxdist=15000,nmin=4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is surprising to me that `log10("Ag_ppm")` doesn't throw the same error, but I have often overcome this problem using `get`:

```
LogSr.idw = idw(log10(get(coln)) ~ 1, locations=NGSA.SPDF, newdata=NGSA.grid,
                maxdist=15000, nmin=4)
```

In most situations, it is a good idea to think of an alternative to using `get`, but due the the formula (`~`) here, and the use of the newdata arguemtn, `get` might be the best solution.